# How to do custom action composition to log request and response in Play 2.3?

Tags: java, playframework-2.3

I'm working on Play 2.3 (Java) application and I need a custom Action Composition to log request and response. With what I've got so far I am able to get the body of request, but not response:

```
import play.libs.F;
import play.mvc.Action;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class LogAction extends Action.Simple {

    public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        //Request body
        String requestBody = ctx.request().body().asText();
        //Need to get response body here
        //String responseBody = ???
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }

}
```

How to I get the response body in this scenario? If it's difficult to do in java, it may as well be in scala, however it has to work with a java controller method `@With` annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        Promise<Result> call = delegate.call(ctx);
        return call.map((r) -> {
            byte[] body = JavaResultExtractor.getBody(r, 0l);
            Logger.info(new String(body));
            return r;
        });
    }
```

You can use `play.core.j.JavaResultExtractor` to extract the body from the response. Keep in mind, `getBody(..)` blocks until response is ready, thus consider calling `onRedeem` instead of `map`.

Comment: JavaResultExtractor.getBody(result, 0L) gives timeout even if i change it from 0 to 100k.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
public class VerboseAction extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {

    public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        Logger.info("Calling action for " + ctx);
        F.Promise<Result> resultPromise = delegate.call(ctx);
        resultPromise.map(result -> {
            Logger.info(result.toScala().header().status());
            Logger.info(result.toScala().body().toString());
            return result;
        });
        return resultPromise;
    }
}
```

The body will be returned as a `play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator`. Now the hard part is to work with this. First you need to understand the concept of `Iteratee` and what role the `Enumerator` plays in it. Hint: think of the `Enumerator` as a *producer* of data and think of the `Iteratee` as the *consumer* of this data.

Now on this `Enumerator` you can *run* an `Iteratee` that will transform the data chunks into the type you want.

The bad news is that you need to implement the `play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee` trait. As you can see it resides in the `api` subpackage, that means it is part of the Scala world in Play. Maybe in this case it woul be much easier to use Scala for this part of your task. Unfortunately I cannot provide you with some example implementation but I hope this would be not that hard. I think this is something really missing on the Java side of Play.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however although it seems to be in the right direction, I'm getting this logged - `play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator$$anon$18@2ae9a7b2` instead of the response body for some reason.