# Play Framework 2.3: using scala action composition in java controller

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

For reasons stemming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157715/play-framework-2-3-custom-action-composition-to-log-request-and-response) I need to write a custom action composition in scala that can be then used in java controller, something like this:

LogAction.scala (Scala Custom Action Composition):

```
import play.api.mvc._

class LogAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {

    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
        Logger.info("Calling action")
        block(request)
    }

}
```

Application.java (Java Controller):

```
import LogAction;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.mvc.With;

public class Application extends Controller {

    @With(LogAction.class)
    public static Result index() {
        return ok(views.html.admin.main.render());
    }

}
```

Is something like this possible? If yes then how? The final goal is to log request and response bodies using this particular action composition.